# Plotting a rectangular matrix into a circle

Tags: matlab, plot, surf, cylindrical

I have generated a rectangular matrix with the azimouth angle changing with rows and the radius changing as you change column. These are meant to represent the relative velocities experienced by a rotating helicopter blade. This produces a matrix called Vmat. I want to plot this to appears in a circle (representing the rotation of the blade)

So far I have tried

```
[R,T] = meshgrid(r,az);      

[x,y] = pol2cart(T,R);      

surf(x,y,Vmat(r,az));
```

which should produce a contoured surface showing velocity as it changes with azimouth angle and radius but it comes up with dimension errors.
I don't mind if it is a 2d contour plot or 3d plot i guess both would be written in a similar way.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 0):

The error is in writing `Vmat(r,az)`, presuming that these are actual values of radius and azimuth, not indexes into your radius and azimuth.  If you want to take only a subset of `Vmat` that's a slightly different matter, but this should work:

```
[R,T] = meshgrid(r,az);  % creates a grid in polar coordinates   
[x,y] = pol2cart(T,R);   % changes those to cartesian for surf
surf(x,y,Vmat);
```

Alternatively you could do a contour plot:

```
h = polar([0 2*pi], [0 max(r)]); % set up polar axes with right scale
delete(h) % remove line
hold on
contour(x,y,Vmat);
```

Comment: Tried them both; surf() continued coming up with dimension errors. The contour plot came up with: The size of X must match the size of Z or
the number of columns of Z.

Comment: If u give me your email i can send you the bits of the code i need to use it on.

Comment: What are the sizes of your `r`, `az`, and `Vmat`?

Comment: r is 13 az is 33 and vmat is 13*33. Its formed in a loop where first az is set in the outside for loop then it loops through the different radius then az goes on one and so on filling up the matrix.